# Finding angles in a triangle

Tags: triangles

If $AD$ is the median to side $BC$ of $\Delta ABC$ & $\angle B =2 \angle C$, then find $\angle B$
[image]

I feel something is missing in the question

Comment: There certainly is something missing. Any triangle with $\angle B=2\angle C$ will do.